How to solve getting Null Auth::user in laravel 11
These are the files that I have for my authentication. I have student, admins, and super_admins.
class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        // Retrieve the authenticated user from the correct guard
        $user = Auth::user();

        // Check user's role and redirect accordingly
        if ($user instanceof \App\Models\Student && $user->hasRole('student')) {
            return redirect()->intended(route('student.dashboard'));
        } elseif ($user instanceof \App\Models\Admin && $user->hasRole('academichead')) {
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        } elseif ($user instanceof \App\Models\SuperAdmin && $user->hasRole('registrar')) {
            return redirect()->intended(route('superadmin.dashboard'));
        } else {
            // Default redirect if no specific role match found
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }
    }
    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}

This is from my LoginController in Auth
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::guard('academichead')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        } elseif (Auth::guard('registrar')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/superadmin/dashboard');
        } elseif (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/user/dashboard');
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('academichead')->check()) {
            Auth::guard('academichead')->logout();
        } elseif (Auth::guard('registrar')->check()) {
            Auth::guard('registrar')->logout();
        } else {
            Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}

This is from my LoginRequest.php
class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $guard;

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate the request's credentials.
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function authenticate(): void
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        $credentials = $this->only('email', 'password');

        // Try to authenticate against multiple guards
        // if (Auth::guard('academichead')->attempt($credentials, $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        //     $this->guard = 'academichead';
        // } elseif (Auth::guard('registrar')->attempt($credentials, $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        //     $this->guard = 'registrar';
        // } elseif (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        //     $this->guard = 'web';
        // } else {
        //     RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        //     throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        //         'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        //     ]);
        // }

        if (Auth::guard('academichead')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $this->guard = 'academichead';
        } elseif (Auth::guard('registrar')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $this->guard = 'registrar';
        } elseif (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $this->guard = 'web';
        } else {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }


        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }

    /**
     * Ensure the login request is not rate limited.
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function ensureIsNotRateLimited(): void
    {
        if (!RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 5)) {
            return;
        }

        event(new Lockout($this));

        $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.throttle', [
                'seconds' => $seconds,
                'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60),
            ]),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the rate limiting throttle key for the request.
     */
    public function throttleKey(): string
    {
        return Str::transliterate(Str::lower($this->string('email')) . '|' . $this->ip());
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated guard.
     */
    public function authenticatedGuard(): string
    {
        return $this->guard;
    }
}

This is from my web.php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Route::get('/admin/dashboard', function () {
//     return view('admin.dashboard.index');
// });

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login.post');
Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

Route::prefix('student')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [StudentController::class, 'index'])->name('student.dashboard');
});

Route::prefix('academichead')->middleware(['auth:academichead'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
});

Route::prefix('registrar')->middleware(['auth:registrar'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [SuperAdminController::class, 'index'])->name('superadmin.dashboard');
});


Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});



require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';

When I log in, only the students will be authenticated. The admins and super_admins can't. I'm not using the default Users because of our requirements.

"How can I authenticate users from different tables" - This won't answer your question, but consider not doing that. Having multiple User classes (Student, Admin, SuperAdmin) is an approach that doesn't work well with Laravel. A User is a User, what you have are multiple Roles, where each User can have 1 (or none/more, etc.) of those Roles, and when they login (via a single User Model), can access certain Routes based on their Role(s). I've seen this question asked many times over last decade, and have yet to see a compelling argument for this way vs a traditional User/Role combo.

@TimLewis The student table have too much information on them. It's also connected to other tables for different purposes to be paired with the admins and super admins. What approach do you suggest on how I can have a work around for this?

Those other questions I've alluded to still haven't been answered, since again, Laravel wasn't really designed to work with multiple User classes. There are ways to link your students, admins and super_admins tables to your users table, as a one-to-one (or even using polymorphism, etc.) I don't have an answer for you using your desired approach, maybe someone will come along and answer this question, but I'd strongly recommend exploring other approaches.
